# Trying to understand the keyword "this" in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function hello() {

    let list = {
        firstName: "Jack"
    }

    return "Hello " + this.firstName;
}

console.log(hello());
```

How does the keyword "this" work? I cant get my head around it. How should I use it and how should I think?
Is there any simple sentence you can associate "this" so its easier to understand?

Comment: `this` is whatever is the runtime context, _unless_ it's inside an arrow function, where it is the context at declaration.

Comment: Most of the time `this` is used to refer to object that calls the function. If you do `someObj.func()` then for the `.func()` function, `this` will be `someObj`.

Comment: If you mean `list.firstName`, you should *not* use `this`.